# High response times for LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, load-testing, performance-testing

We are load testing this Single-Sign-On(SSO) website with multiple virtual users. The issue is that transaction response times start peaking once the user load crosses 20 users. The site performs authentication against LDAP server. Once the user is authenticated, an SAML response is generated which is then sent back to the LDAP client. The SAML response is then sent to another server to generate an Token value upon validation. Finally the validated Open Token is sent back along with  a valid confirmation message.

The issue at hand is high response times for LDAP authentication to complete. The CPU and Memory utilization of the LDAP servers are well within limits even at a maximum peak user load of 500 virtual users; albeit with response times scaling 500 seconds(ideally should be sub-second). What can be the usual causes for LDAP directory service to result in high response times? For more information, we used multiple load generators from various locations; all functioning well(normal CPU,disk,memory utilization)- just to confirm there were no glitches in load generation. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your LDAP server used it may provide an access log which tells you how much time the LDAP requests take and how they look like.

The 2 most common issues are clients perform sub-optimal searches (typically LDAP servers don't have query optimizations as RDMBS have) and a missing indexes on the server side.